# Gradient Descent (Linear regression with one variable)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave

i was trying to implement Gradient Descent (linear regression with one variable).I have some doubts with the below code.

In the attachment ex1data1 column 1 and 2 represent X and y respectively.
Initially i was trying to implement the algorithm as below

```
for iter=i:iterations

 for i=1:2
     h=(theta'*X')';
     s=sum((h-y).*X(i));
     s1=s*alpha/m;
     theta(i)=theta(i)-s1;

  end
 ..
end
```

but i could not arrive at the optimal value for theta.

Then i tried  vectorization

```
for iter=i:iterations
   h=(theta'*X')';
   theta = theta -((1/m) * (h - y)' * X)' * alpha;
end
```

and got the optimal value.

Could you please explain what is the difference between both code? i found it same. its been told that vectorization is preferred over loop, but just want to know out of curiosity. Is there anything particular i need to concentrate while trying to find a vectored formula?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.Issue was with the step calculating s.
Initially it was `s=sum((h-y).*X(i));`. But it should be `s=sum((h-y).*X(:,i));`

```
for i=1:2,
     h=(theta'*X')';
     s=sum((h-y).*X(:,i));
     s1=s*(alpha/m);
     theta(i)=theta(i)-s1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

in matrices axb is not same as bxa so hear h = X*theta is should be used to match dimensions of y

```
temp = zeros(2,1);
    for iter = 1:num_iters

        temp(1)= theta(1)-alpha*(1/m)*sum(((X*theta)-y).*X(:,1));

        temp(2)= theta(2)-alpha*(1/m)*sum(((X*theta)-y).*X(:,2));
        theta = temp;

    theta = temp;
end
```